# CakePHP HABTM add/edit problems

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have the following relationship:

Edition:

```
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Band' => array(
        'className' => 'Band',
        'joinTable' => 'bands_editions',
        'foreignKey' => 'edition_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'band_id',
        'unique' => true,
    )
);
```

Band:

```
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Edition' => array(
        'className' => 'Edition',
        'joinTable' => 'bands_editions',
        'foreignKey' => 'band_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'edition_id',
        'unique' => true,
    )
);
```

BandsController:

```
public function add()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $this->Band->create();
        if($this->Band->save($this->request->data))
            doSomething();
        else
            doSomethingElse();
    }
}

public function edit($id = NULL)
{
    $this->Band->id = $id;
    if(!$this->Band->exists())
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Not found'));

    if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))
    {
        if($this->Band->save($this->request->data))
            doSomething();
        else
            doSomethingElse();
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->Band->read(NULL, $id);
    }
}
```

When I try to populate Bands with add(), everything goes well, but as soon as I call edit(), Cake stops with this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function schema() on a non-object

Debugging, I found that the error is fired when the parser reaches the check about the type of the request.

Which is my error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , I didn't see if it works

```
public function edit($id = null){
    if(!$id){
        throw new NotFoundException(__("Invalid Post"));
    }

    $band = $this->Band->findById($id);

    if (!$band) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Post'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $this->Band->id = $id;
        if ($this->Band->save($this->request->data)) {
            doSomething();
        }
        else {
            doDomething();
        }
    }

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $Band;
    }
}
```